# Foreign Key Constraint incorrectly formed - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables "theaters" and "cubelists".  The "theaters" table is already created.  In the "cubelists" table,I have made "area" and "stn" as foreign keys to the table "theaters".  But I get an error the foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.  But I couldn't figure out the error.

```
Schema::create('theaters', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->string('theater_name');
    $table->string('area_name');
    $table->string('station');
    $table->primary(array('theater_name','area_name','station'));
    $table->text('address');
    $table->bigInteger('phno');
    $table->string('contact_person');

});

Schema::create('cubelists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('mvie_name');
    $table->foreign('mvie_name')->references('movie_name')->on('movies');
    $table->string('thtr_name');
    $table->foreign('thtr_name')->references('theater_name')-
    >on('theaters');
    $table->string('area');
    $table->foreign('area')->references('area_name')->on('theaters');
    $table->string('stn');
    $table->foreign('stn')->references('station')->on('theaters');
    $table->primary(array('mvie_name','thtr_name','area','stn'));
    $table->string('type');
    $table->string('subtype');
    $table->date('validity');
    $table->string('show');

});
```

Error is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\boras>php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `boras_cachii`.`#sql-a10_
  5a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
   `cubelists` add constraint cubelists_area_foreign foreign key (`area`) reference
  s `theaters` (`area_name`))



      [PDOException]
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `boras_cachii`.`#sql-a10_
      5a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Depending on your DB engine, the syntax may need to be `add constraint [name] foreign key ([column]) references [table] ([othercolumn]) on delete [do something] on update [do something]`, but the "on delete/update" part seems to be missing. I would guess you need to add `->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')` to your call, to ensure it gets added.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think OP should be using MariaDB since he uses XAMPP

Comment: I tried adding ->onDelete('cascade') ->onUpdate('cascade') but that doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key constraint should reference a candidate key. I don't know what *cubelist* means, but you *probably* want to reference the primary key in "theaters". That is, you *probably* want one foreign key constraint to reference the *three* columns theater_name, area_name, and station. Not individual constraints on each of those columns.

MySQL might or might not let you get away with what you originally tried to do, but don't do that anyway. Search [13.1.17.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for "does not enforce".